# MySQLで、16進数カラーコードを格納するデータ型について

Tags: mysql

**MySQLで、(下記のような)#を除外した16進数カラーコードを格納したいのですが、**

> 3F51B5
>
> 33691E

※デフォルト値は下記に設定する予定

> A1887F

---

**Q1.データ型は何が良いですか？**
16進数なので固定の長さ(？)だから、CHAR型の方が良いですか？

- CHAR型
- VARCHAR型
- 上記以外

---

**Q2.データ型の長さは？**
長さのカウントの仕方は、CHARでもVARCHARでも同じですか？　日本語文字ではないので、この場合は6文字ですか？

- CHAR(6)？
- VARCHAR(6)？

環境
MySQL5.7

Comment: 参考までに、`BINARY` 型で格納する方法も考えられます。[Mysql Hexadecimal color code store in binary datatype](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/mysql-hexadecimal-color-code-store-in-binary-datatype)

Comment: MySQLで色相の計算（例えば補色の算出とか）を実行しますか？

Comment: 24bit color なら普通に `INT` で良いのでは

Comment: そのデータを、どのように使うのですか？　RGBに分けて何かの計算に使うとか、24bitRGBのまま使うとか、、、

Comment: @metropolis。BINARY 型が良く分からないのですが、INSERTする時はUNHEX()でバイナリ変換し、SELECTする時はHEX()で16進数文字列へ戻す、ということですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so,@Fumu 7。今回の用途は、CSSで色指定する際、使用するだけです。ただ、今回の件とは別(異なるデータベース)で、「Lab」色系などとの相互変換処理を試してみる予定があります。コメントの意味が分からないのですが、「色計算を行う」かどうかで、格納するデータ型は変わってくるのですか？

Comment: @774RR。16進数はINT型に格納できるのですか？ それとも100001…みたいに2進数へ変換して格納する、という意味ですか？

Comment: @re9 はい、そうです。ただ、CSSでの色指定に使うだけでしたら `CHAR(6)`(固定長)で十分かと思います。

Comment: 用途次第っす。文字列 `CHAR(6)` だと HTML/CSS 中の色指定に使うには便利ですが RGB/HSV 変換しようと思ったら色数値に変換する必要があります。 `INT` にしておけば色変換関数に渡すのが楽ですし、データベースの記憶装置消費量も減り高速になります。ある色値があるとき、それを `INT`で表現するというのははコンピュータにとって便利な表記をするってことで `CHAR(6)` 表記するのは人間にとってわかりやすいだけで、両社とも意味的には同じっすよ。